# Is there a way to avoid deeply nested groups in SVGs created from TikZ PDFs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, svg

Say I have a document with many individual TikZ pictures (in my cases, dozens):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,20} {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,circle,fill=gray!20!white] {\i};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\end{document}
```

I use LuaLaTeX for compilation to PDF.
Now, I want to use those programmed graphics as building blocks in Inkscape for interactive image creation (creating an appartment plan, if you must know):

[image]

Writing that door macro took me all night, but I digress. The point is, I want to import the PDF into Inkscape (which works very well in most situations!) and then copy-paste individual pieces of furniture -- or, in our example, circles -- from one document to another and arrange them in consensus-able ways.

Here's the problem:

[image]

The 20th picture is nested 20 deep in groups -- which requires at least 40 well placed clicks to get to (more, usually). I don't understand where this nesting comes from, but it critically breaks my workflow.

So, from the perspective of LaTeX: What are ways to control, if at all, the SVG result, however indirectly? Specifically, grouping and naming of groups.

Comment: [Related question about Inkscape](https://superuser.com/q/1561309/74934).

Comment: If you typeset with `dvilualatex mwe` and `dvisvgm --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 mwe` you get an SVG with a single group. The group has `id="page1"`.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks, can confirm! It's good to keep dvisvgm in mind. However, the output is a lot worse than what I get from the lualatex+inkscape pipeline -- and _no_ groups are also not very useful. :/

Comment: What's wrong with the SVG output? It looks very clean to me. Also, one has full control over SVG-grouping using `dvisvgm:raw` specials.

Comment: See for yourself: [comparison](https://imgur.com/a/bOApDI8). Maybe I'm "holding it wrong" (there are warnings), but whenever I tried dvisvgm in the past (not all too often, to be fair), the comparison came out this way. I will check again with a full 2020 install at some point (current experiment built in a container are _worse_).

Comment: To get the labels right, use `dvisvgm` option `--no-fonts` (as in my answer). This tells `dvisvgm` to convert font glyphs into SVG paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dvisvgm` one has full control over svg-grouping of objects.

In the example code below, every TikZ node is embedded in an SVG group that gets an individual ID:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,20} {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \special{dvisvgm:raw <g id="node\i">}
    \node[draw,circle,fill=gray!20!white] {\i};
    \special{dvisvgm:raw </g>}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\end{document}
```

Example `mwe.tex` to be typeset with

```
dvilualatex mwe
dvilualatex mwe
dvisvgm --no-fonts --zoom=-1 mwe
```

[image]

Comment: Quick question: I see you snuck in `fontenc`. Could you quickly comment on why? It definitely makes a difference, I just checked that, but _why_?

Comment: FWIW, `\special` can also be used outside of the `tikzpicture` (which feels "more right" to me here), and [the output](https://imgur.com/a/WFoC6TQ) is perfect! (Hint for googlers: `id` needs to be unique, obviously.)

Comment: It instructs dvilualatex to use/embed the LatinModern variant of the CM typeface, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized while writing together the MWE that if I convert instead of import:

```sh
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode mwe.tex

# This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
# whoops ...
# <snip>

inkscape  --export-type=svg mwe.pdf > mwe.svg
# Inkscape 1.0
```

the resulting SVG does *not* have the nesting problem! Its groups are a lot less useful, but at least I can select what I want to move (and manually group).